# Entity Framework 5 with Repositories retrieving old data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, entity-framework-5, unit-of-work

I have a problem with EF5. I am using MVC 4.5

I am trying to make the 1 context per request "pattern".

I am not using "unit of work" pattern, nor testing or DI.

I am using the Generic Repository pattern to interact with DB. Each repository uses the same context mantained by a singleton "DataContextManager".

In each request in the global asax I refresh the context, but something wrong is happening: ie: I have a paged list and moving by the pages if i change data in DB manualy it doesnt refresh correctly. **It's not an HTML cache issue, i tested it.**

I know is a EF Context problem because i have "something like this":

```
private static Context C; //for the singleton. And in global.asax

public Application_BeginRequest()
{    
    DataContextManager.RefreshNew();
}

protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Domain.DataContextManager.Dispose();
}
```

And the first time the list works and in the second page i get an error saying that the 
Context is disposed.

I read something of using the context in Static variables, but i don't know whats happening. I would like to use something simple like this, because to implement the UnitOfWork pattern i will need to change a lot of code.

Here is a little snnipet of my classes:

```
 public class DataContextManager
    {
        private static Entities _Context;

        private const string ConnectionString = "connString";

        public static Entities Context
        {
            get
            {
                if (DataContextManager._Context == null)
                    DataContextManager._Context = new Entities(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConnectionString].ConnectionString);

                return DataContextManager._Context;
            }
        }

        //This method is not necessary but made it for testing
        public static void RefreshNew()
        {                
            DataContextManager._Context = new Entities(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConnectionString].ConnectionString);
        }

        public static void Dispose()
        {
            if (DataContextManager._Context != null)
            {   
                DataContextManager._Context.Dispose();
                DataContextManager._Context = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

And repositories use DataContextManager like this:

```
public class BaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        internal Entities context;
        internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

        public BaseRepository()
            : this(DataContextManager.Context)
        {
        }

        public BaseRepository(Entities context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Pablo.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you really need the manager class, since everything seems to just access the `DbContext` property.

That being said, you should normally avoid using `DbContext` in a static class; I don't have any canonical source to back that up, but my personal experience has been that it at some point causes more problems than any benefit having a static class provides. So, I'd update the manager like so:

```
public class DataContextManager
{
    private readonly string connectionToUse = string.Empty;

    private Entities _context;

    public Entities Context
    {
        get
        {
            if (_context == null)
            {
                _context = new Entities(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionToUse].ConnectionString);
            }

            return _context;
        }
    }

    public DataContextManager()
    {
        connectionToUse = "connString";
    }

    public DataContextManager(string key)
    {
        connectionToUse = key;
    }


    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);

        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposeAll)
    {
        if (disposeAll)
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
        _context = null;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then you simply add a protected field to each of your controllers and instantiate the manager in the controller's constructor:

```
protected DataContextManager Manager = null;

public HomeController()
{
    Manager = new DataContextManager();

    // or
    //
    //__manager = new DataContextManager("connection-To-Use");
}
```

If all of your controllers use the same `DbContext` class, you could create a `BaseController` class that inherits `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` and move the manager into it, which saves some duplication.